# Upgrade RAM memory in Galaxy Y

Tags: samsung, ram, samsung-galaxy-y

I am using Samsung Galaxy Y Device . The device has only 512 MB RAM 
available. I want to upgrade the RAM memory to 1 GB. I have a SannDisk 8 Gb class 10 
memory card. Is there any way to boost the RAM?